# Docker gets wrong index from app

Tags: docker, nginx

As I was working on "Dockerizing my App" following the instructions in the link below:

https://www.joyent.com/blog/video-training-dockerize-applications

I got some trouble getting the right index.html

I used yarn build in order to generate the minified files to launche the Frontend App I'm working on, and adde the following in my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

Where /dist is the folder which contains the generated files of the App.

Then I run the following commands:

```
$ docker build -t some-content-nginx . 

$ docker run -d -p 80:80 some-content-nginx
```

To finally get that the nginx service it's running at 172.17.0.2:80

But when I try to see it in the browser, it redirects to

172.17.0.2

and also doesn't show anything until I add

172.17.0.2/index.html

But then it shows the index.html default page from nginx

So, I run

```
$ docker exec -it <name-of-the-container> /bin/bash
```

to see if the **index.html** got **"overwriten"** as well, but when I get into the path /usr/share/nginx/html I do find the correct files, so I go by running

```
root@<container-ID>: /usr/share/nginx/html# cat index.html
```

In order to verify if it's the right file so it turns out that... yes, the right **index.html** is in place!

So my main question, why is my container showing the wrong **index.html**?

And how should I attempt to solve this problem? I'm really newbie using this, so any help would be appreciated a lot.

***Note:*** there's no other **index.html** or even a strange copy of it inside the same folder or at any folder.

**Edit:** Corrected ip addresses

Comment: Is root location for localhost in nginx set to `/usr/share/nginx/html` ? Check the config in your container.

Comment: `172.17.02:80` is not a valid IP. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @AlexKarshin my mistake, I posted invalid ip adresses, just fixed that in the post.

Comment: @OlegButuzov Yep, it's set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue. It was the cache from my browser that kept the old **index.html**. My apologies for opening a question for this and thank you to the people who answered.